# Pandas, resampling with weighted average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, weighted

I want to know how to perform a resampling with a weighted average on each columns based on the time between each measurement.

Here is an extract of the dataframe (the first column is in m³/h and the second in %):

```
                DEBITS  VOLETS
datetime                           
2014-01-21 00:03:03     NaN   49.93
2014-01-21 00:09:54   55.40     NaN
2014-01-21 00:12:59     NaN   47.72
2014-01-21 00:19:51   48.18     NaN
2014-01-21 00:22:57     NaN   49.44
2014-01-21 00:30:00   65.50     NaN
2014-01-21 00:33:04     NaN   49.37
2014-01-21 00:39:55   63.24     NaN
2014-01-21 00:43:00     NaN   49.69
2014-01-21 00:49:52   65.13     NaN
2014-01-21 00:52:57     NaN   48.75
2014-01-21 00:59:59   47.75     NaN
2014-01-21 01:03:05     NaN   48.50
2014-01-21 01:09:57   61.09     NaN
2014-01-21 01:13:01     NaN   48.16
2014-01-21 01:19:51   58.56     NaN
2014-01-21 01:22:57     NaN   50.09
2014-01-21 01:29:59   62.69     NaN
2014-01-21 01:33:04     NaN   48.55
2014-01-21 01:39:56   56.73     NaN
2014-01-21 01:43:01     NaN   49.06
2014-01-21 01:49:52   56.73     NaN
2014-01-21 01:52:57     NaN   48.73
2014-01-21 01:59:58   62.60     NaN
```

**Question modified July 2, 2014**

I know I need to use a function as a parameter of "how" but I do not know how to articulate it.

```
df.resample('H', how='mean')
```

But I think the np.average of the numpy library function should be used, but NaN seems to cause an error.

```
np.average(data['DEBITS'], weights=data.index)
```

How to articulate this two function together to make this weighted average?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is it not rigorous to average the flow rate like that? Flow rate is linear with time, as is the mean, sounds fine to me. Second, if you resample, then the time steps are regular, and so can be factored outside of the sum to get cumulative flow - you can just need to multiply the whole column by the time step.

Comment: You're right, it is perfectly possible to make an average but better with weighted as mentioned.Nevertheless, it would be more accurate to perform this operation accumulated weighted.
For the second point mentioned, perform a simple summation is not good because it is a ratio, but also because the number of values ​​in one time varies every hour.

Comment: IT shouldn't matter though, resampling the data should just be an interpolation. The cumulative flow is just the integral of the flow rate, and when the time between the steps is constant, then the integral and the sum*time_step are going to be very similar (depending on how the integral bins the flowrates).

Comment: I understand what you talk about. Precisely, is the resample function with the "mean" parameter do a weighted average (to adjust to the irregularity of the time step) ? Otherwise, how to do?